# Theme.json stopped updating in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, themes, updates

I'm working on my fse (full site editing) project in wordpress since a few days. I edit the theme.json file daily to change/add font sizes or similar thing. But since today nothing changes when I change something in the theme.json file. If I delete the file completely then I don't have any styles or similar anymore but if I add it again with just 2 lines of code it's still loaded the way it was yesterday. I have already tried several browsers, deleted the browser cache. In addition, I have also restarted my dev server which has also brought nothing.

Here is my theme.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "appearanceTools": true,
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "1140px",
            "wideSize": "1140px"
        },
        "color": {
            "palette": [
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-Black",
                    "color": "#2c2c2c",
                    "name": "CHE-Black"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-White",
                    "color": "#fff",
                    "name": "CHE-White"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-Blue",
                    "color": "#0b76b5",
                    "name": "CHE-Blue"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-Blue-Light",
                    "color": "#9fb1bf",
                    "name": "CHE-Blue-Light"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-Red",
                    "color": "#ba2e24",
                    "name": "CHE-Red"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-Gold",
                    "color": "#d2aa50",
                    "name": "CHE-Gold"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "CHE-Grey",
                    "color": "#9a9a9a",
                    "name": "CHE-Grey"
                }
            ]
        },
        "spacing": {
            "blockGap": true,
            "margin": true,
            "padding": true,
            "units": [
                "%",
                "px",
                "em",
                "rem",
                "vh",
                "vw"
            ]
        },
        "typography": {
            "dropCap": true,
            "fontStyle": true,
            "fontWeight": true,
            "letterSpacing": true,
            "lineHeight": true,
            "textDecoration": true,
            "textTransform": true,
            "fontFamilies": [{
                "fontFamily": "serif",
                "slug": "serif",
                "name": "serif"
            }
            ],
            "fontSizes": [
                {
                    "size": "1.2em",
                    "slug": "p-standard",
                    "name": "p-standard"
                },
                {
                    "size": "2.5em",
                    "slug": "h2",
                    "name": "h2"
                },
                {
                    "size": "1.825em",
                    "slug": "h3",
                    "name": "h3"
                },
                {
                    "size": "1.5em",
                    "slug": "h4",
                    "name": "h4"
                },
                {
                    "size": "1.3em",
                    "slug": "h5",
                    "name": "h5"
                },
                {
                    "size": "0.9em",
                    "slug": "h6",
                    "name": "h6"
                },
                {
                    "size": "14px",
                    "slug": "nav",
                    "name": "nav"
                },
                {
                    "size": "13px",
                    "slug": "footer",
                    "name": "footer"
                },
                {
                    "size": "15px",
                    "slug": "button",
                    "name": "button"
                }
            ]
        }

    },
    "templateParts": [
        {
            "name": "header",
            "area": "header",
            "title": "Header"
        },
        {
            "name": "footer",
            "area": "footer",
            "title": "Footer"
        }
    ]

}
```

> Restartet Dev Server
> Tried several Browsers
> Deleted Browser cache

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

To disable caching of theme.json, you need to define the following in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development' );
```

Hope that helps!